# Laravel how to store an array in to database

Tags: laravel

I store data into array[], when i do dd(($request)); i can see the array with the date.

Question how i can store it inside the DB?

**blade**

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label for="qualifiche">qualifiche:</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="array[]" value="uno" > Uno <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="array[]" value="due"> Due <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="array[]" value="tre"> Tre <br>
                </div>
```

Comment: Why all inputs have same name ? By this u can just get one of them

Comment: @Itisallyours because they're combined in an array

Comment: @Itisallyours Because is an array

Comment: And what is the field and table you want to insert ? What's field type

Comment: use `serialize($request->input('array'))` to store and `unserialize($model->field_name) ` to retrieve

Comment: @Itisallyours i wanna store array[data] into the DB (varchar)

Comment: There's no `array` fieldtype in a database, you need to either loop the input and save as a relationship between table A and B, split into a comma/pipe separated string and save to a `VARCHAR` field, convert to JSON and save to a `JSON` field, etc etc.

Comment: @Matteo check eh answer below

Comment: you can also use `$casts` which will serialize/unserialize for you: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting just set the field type to `TEXT` or `JSON` and add the field to the `$casts` array as shown in the docs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two main options:

**Option 1:**

first Serialize the array and save it:

```
$arr = serialize($request['array']);
```

Then when you retrieve the data you do something like:
    // $model->attribute will be replaced with ur Model name and attribute
    $data = unserialize($model->attribute);

Here is the documentation: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

**Option 2:**

Construct a string manually from the array and save it as a string:
    // `!!` is the delimiter you can use whatever u want...
    $data = implode('!!', $request['array]);

and you can have the array back using:

```
$array = explode('!!', $model->attribute);
```

**For Laravel:**

You can write a getter to get the data as an array without doing it manually:

```
public function getSomethingAttribute($value)
{
    // if using serialize
    return unserialize($value);
    // or if using implode
    return explode('!!', $value)

}
```

**Extra:**

You can also store it as JSON if the database field is set as JSON or Text...if it's the case parse the array and save it.

Comment: one question i can add the option 1 inside  the " create" or outside

Comment: @Matteo whatever u like: `Model::create(['attribute' => serialize($request['array']) .... ])` or `$data = $request['array'];`  ..then create using `$data`