# laravel return array to string conversion error

Tags: php, laravel

I have store method in my controller and it returns this errors:

## Errors

Console `Preview tab`

```
exception: "ErrorException"
file: "C:\........\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Str.php"
line: 419
message: "Array to string conversion"
```

Console `Response tab`

```
   {
        "file": "C:\\........\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\Api\\Front\\CartController.php",
        "line": 380,
        "function": "save",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model",
        "type": "->"
    },
```

## Code

```
public function checkout(Request $request)
{
    $user = auth('api')->user();
    $cartItems = CartStorage::where('user_id', $user->id)->get();
    $address = AddressUser::where('id', $request->input('address'))->first();

    foreach($cartItems as $item) {
        $cartData = $item->cart_data;
        // add to orders table
        try {
            $order = new Order();
            $order->ordernu = 'Si-'.mt_rand(1000000000, 9999999999);
            $order->user_id = $user->id;
            $order->order_data = $cartData;
            $order->quantity = $cartData['quantity'];
            $order->price = $request->input('totalPrice');
            $order->courier = $request->input('courier');
            $order->courier_service = $request->input('courierService');
            $order->shippingcode = $request->input('shippingcode');
            $order->shipping_price = $request->input('shippingPrice');
            $order->address = $address->address;
            $order->kecamatan = $address->kecamatan;
            $order->kelurahan = $address->kelurahan;
            $order->kota = $address->kota;
            $order->provinsi = $address->provinsi;
            $order->postalcode = $address->postalcode;
            $order->weight = $request->input('weight');
            $order->phone = $request->input('phone');
            $order->buyer_name = $user->name;
            $order->buyer_email = $user->email;
            $order->note = $request->input('note');
            $order->received = false;
            $order->save();

            // reduce stock of each product
            foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
                $cartData = $item->cart_data;
                $product = Product::find($cartData['productId']);
                $product->decrement('qty', $cartData['quantity']);
            }

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return response($e->getMessage(), 400);
        }
    }
}
```

> Note: I've tested `dd` every single data that I placed in `order` column and all are getting true values.

**Any idea?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

> $order->order_data = $cartData;

`$cartData` is an array and cannot be saved into database directly.

That's why you got Array to string conversion error.

Comment: Exactly, I've just solved it with `json_encode($cartData);` thank you

Answer (score 2):

I was seeking for the same solution and this worked for me. Assuming your `order_data` column on the Order model is of type json. Define the casts property in your `Order` model with `order_data` as an array. You won't need json_encode if you use it this way as laravel will convert the array into json for you.

```
class Order extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'order_data' => 'array'
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this because you try to store array as a string into the database, to store array into the database you have either :

1. `$data_to_store=json_encode($array)` then when callback `$array=json_decode($db_data)`
2. `$data_to_store=serialize($array)` then when callback `$array=unserialize($db_data)`
3. `$data_to_store= implode('!!', $array)` then when callback `$array = explode('!!', $db_data)`

check also this amazing [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49259117/laravel-how-to-store-an-array-in-to-database)